# CSS contents overlapping sidebar only after 2nd post

Tags: css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

In this page: http://kobisart.tumblr.com/
the main posts are overlapping the sidebar only after the second post. It occurs on both pages of the blog (navigate by adding /page/1 /page/2 to url)

Some additional info:

-only occurs after the 2nd newest post. even when I post new content, it's always the 2nd

- I changed the tags portion of the posts. added line(hr) and tags underneath

Looking to change my theme to normal ( posts not overlapping )

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the first entry inside a div called "contents" but then all the other entries are outside of that div, therefore they are being aligned relative to the edge of the body, whereas the first entry is being aligned relative to the edge of the contents div.

EDIT: You have:

```
<body> 
  <div id="sidebar"></div> 
  <div id="content"> 
    ENTRY 1 
  </div>
  REST OF ENTRIES. 
</body>
```

What you want is to put all your entries inside the content div.

Comment: I searched "contents" but there doesn't seem to be a result

Comment: although there are many results for "content" if that's what you mean,, which one are you talking about ?

Comment: @qlien Yes I meant content sorry. I've updated my answer with the code you have now.